# integral_constant and template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr, clang++

I would like to capture compile time constant integers passed to a function into templated types. The future goal is to roll my own (very limited) expression template that creates expressions from very simple expressions (sums of compile time constant int and in variables) such as: -2*i + 3*k.

I am starting very slowly, I have the following code:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo (int i) : i_(i) {}

  int i_;
};

template <int N> int operator*(std::integral_constant<int, N> i, Foo j) {
  return N * j.i_;
}

int main(void) {
  std::integral_constant<int, 2> k;
  int i = k * Foo(3);
  cout << i << endl;

  int j = 2 * Foo(3);
  cout << j << endl;
}
```

The template argument deduction fails for 2*Foo(3).
I have read that there is no such thing as constexpr parameters to a function.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want ?

Comment: make the operaator, constructor, and result "constexpr".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't make it working unfortunately: I constexpr'ed the definition of j, the operator and the Foo constructor, I still get the same template deduction error with both gcc-4.6 and clang++. Would you mind posting a modified version that compiles ? Also, in general, Foo may not be a constexpr but a more general term in my expression.

Comment: I doubt you can turn the 2 into an integral_constant<int,2>. You would have to write at least I(2) or something like that where I is a macro. What people do in expression templates is have a type int_cst with a member int where they store the number 2. Not exactly the same...

Comment: oh, Yeah, I completely failed to notice the `2`.  `int` cannot be converted to a `integral_constant<int,2>` in any way, regardless of template deduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that without templates. This answer more or less expands @MooingDuck's suggestion into concrete code, which you might find easier to understand:

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo (int i) : i_(i) {}
    int i_;
};

constexpr int operator*(int i, Foo j) {
    return i * j.i_;
}

int main(void) {
    integral_constant<int, 2> k;

    constexpr int i = k * Foo(3);
    static_assert(i == 6, "Error!");

    constexpr int j = 2 * Foo(3);
    static_assert(j == 6, "Error!");
}
```

Comment: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=90398ee0c8dd684a0cf53f6fb34dbe7e oh hey, `integral_constant<int, 2>` has an implicit conversion to `int`?  I didn't know that!  Is that new?  This code is fine apperently.

Comment: @MooingDuck: it's specified in § 20.9.3 of the C++ Standard. `integral_constant<>` has a `constexpr` conversion operator to the underlying type (and yes, the operator is not marked as `explicit`)